# Flash animations editor

Tags: flash

What application should I use for creating Flash animations for a website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adobe Flash (http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/)

Answer (score 2):

For other options (free software), check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075/can-i-develop-flash-without-buying-anything) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174/foss-tools-for-flash-development).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SWiSH Max2](http://www.swishzone.com/index.php?area=products&product=max) for a few years now (well, SWiSH Max then the second one). It's very much the "FrontPage" of Flash editing but it's got the advantage of being reasonably professional and easy to use and relatively inexpensive ($149 compared to $699 for Adobe Flash CS3, though I think I paid $99 for it so it's gone up in price).

It has a free 30-day trial.